# Is it meaningful to describe an IGBT as desaturating?

Tags: transistors, current, igbt

I've heard IGBTs described as desaturating if too much current passes through them, particularly in the context of drivers with desat protection. My understanding of an NPN BJT is that it is in saturation mode as long as the B-E voltage and B-C voltage are positive. Obviously this definition does not apply to IGBTs. The curves on every IGBT data sheet I've seen show a typical junction drop relationship between voltage and current collector-emitter when the device is gated on. What happens off the edge of the sheet, though, is not clear to me.

I see two possibilities.

1. The curve doesn't change off the edge of the sheet. The only disadvantages to running a given device at higher currents than spec'd are thermal, and the general rule that running off the data sheet is not recommended behavior.
2. The curve does change off the edge of the sheet; put too much current through the device and it goes into an analog mode. The losses start going up even faster than extrapolations from the given curve would indicate, leading to rapid catastrophic failure.

Which is the deal? Is there physical meaning to describing an IGBT as desaturating, like a BJT? Or is it just a way of saying "instantaneous overcurrent"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've heard straight from an [Infineon](https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/index.html) engineer that the IGBT's Vce/Ic curve *does* change off the edge of the datasheet. Enough collector current and the device comes out of saturation. He even had experimental data and waveforms, but unfortunately I don't have permission to post them.

Answer (score 2):

One useful definition of saturation & desaturation as applied to IGBTs is:

> Output and Saturation characteristics. These curves show the relationship between three parameters:
> gate voltage, collector current and collector-emitter voltage at different temperatures. They are useful to identify the transition between full enhancement and “linear mode”, i.e. ***the state when the collector current is determined by the gate voltage and not by the load***.

This quote was copied from the document ref below (I added the bold italics).
Infineon, AN-983 July 2012, page 13, see link 1.

So, "linear" (or de-saturation) operation is when the collector current is determined by the gate voltage, not by the load.  "Saturation" is when the collect current is determined by the load, not the gate voltage (assuming the IGBT is not cut-off, ie: when Vge is well below the Vge threshold).

However, in practice, IGBTs are usually used as a switch rather than a linear amplifier, so "de-saturation" is usually meant to indicate when the collector current has exceeded the intended rating of the device, causing the voltage across the collector-emitter to increase which then causes power dissipation to exceed safe levels, which could result in device over-temperature and eventually failure.  De-saturation can be caused by either (a) excessive collector current, (b) insufficient gate-emitter voltage, or (c) a combination of both (a) & (b).

Link 1:
https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-IGBT_Characteristics-AN-v01_00-EN.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a40153559f8d921224

Answer (score 1):

Be it a BJT or a MOSFET, if there is too much current it will no longer be fully saturating and for a heavy duty switching circuit this is usually the time to say farewell to the device. I see no difference when using an IGBT.

Answer (score 1):

If you were to define "saturated" as \$V_{CE} > V_{GE}\$ then for an 'on' gate voltage of, say, 12V it would be desaturated iff \$V_{CE}\$ > 12V. That would be an indication of something bad happening and it would be time to switch it off fast (but not too fast, or that itself could cause damage).

In reality, that definition does not seem to be widely used, and \$V_{CE(SAT)}\$is used loosely to describe the 'on' \$V_{CE}\$ voltage with reasonable collector current and gate voltage. Thus "desaturated" means a reasonable 'on' gate voltage and an unreasonably high \$V_{CE}\$, indicating an unreasonably high collector current.

Answer (score 0):

I made several gate drivers for IGBTs.  We added a circuit that measures the Vce of the device while on.  If the voltage is too much, we turn off the Gate!  This saves the transistor.  In some cases I measure the C current but watching to too much C-E voltage gives me about the same information.